# Find objects in Core Data entities like a JOIN or WHERE statement

Tags: objective-c, sql, cocoa-touch, core-data, entity-relationship

I have two Entities and I want to do a JOIN in Core Data. I know Core Data is not a MYSQL Database but I don't know how I can explain it otherwise.

Here are my Entities:
[Entitys.png http://img833.imageshack.us/img833/226/bildschirmfoto20120110u.png](http://img833.imageshack.us/img833/226/bildschirmfoto20120110u.png)

EntitySetsCards can have many notes(EntityNotes).
1 --------------------------------------------------> n Relationship.

EntitySetsCards contains the main rows and EntityNotes should be displayed if
 **EntitySetsCards.cardId == EntityNotes.notesCardId**

In mysql, I would do this(query1):

```
SELECT * FROM EntitySetsCards  
INNER JOIN EntityNotes ON EntitySetsCars.cardId = EntityNotes.notes_cardId
```

or this(query2):

```
SELECT * FROM EntitySetsCards, EntityNotes  
WHERE EntitySetsCars.cardId = EntityNotes.notes_cardId
```

How can I do a query like the code above(query2)?

Comment: In `MySQL` you would have an error with that :)

Comment: Sorry, i cant see the mistake. whats wrong?

Comment: In MySQL is something like this: `SELECT * FROM EntitySetsCards, EntityNotes WHERE EntitySetsCars.cardId = EntityNotes.notes_cardId` **OR** this `SELECT * FROM EntitySetsCards INNER JOIN EntityNotes 
ON EntitySetsCars.cardId = EntityNotes.notes_cardId`

Comment: thank you. i have corrected my code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CoreData is not a relational datastore. It is an object store. Simply get the `notes` property of an `EntitySetsCards` and the objects will be instantiated automagically.